# Cartesian product of Poisson processes

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Consider $n$ smooth, compactly supported functions $\phi_1,\dots, \phi_n \in C_c^\infty(\mathbf{R})$, and generate $n$ independent Poisson spatial processes $N_1,\dots,N_n$ on $\mathbf{R}$, each with intensity functions given by the functions $\phi_i$. Has anyone made a study of the probability distribution of the product $N_1 \times \dots \times N_n$, i.e. the product measure $N_1 \times \dots \times N_n$ such that

$$(N_1 \times \dots \times N_n)(B_1 \times \dots \times B_n) = N_1(B_1) \dots N_n(B_n).$$

In particular, what techniques are there for obtaining a formula for

$$ \mathbf{P} \left( (N_1 \times \dots \times N_n)(B) = 0 \right), $$

where $B$ is an arbitrary open set of $\mathbf{R}^{dn}$. If this has been heavily studied, is there a name for the spatial process $N_1 \times \dots \times N_n$?